# uiwebview on a button click not going back to the url passed in that button action

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I am using a uiwebview and passed a url over it ...

But on an external link i want a button and on that click I want to go back on a particular web address.

But page is just loading not going on that url.

Please help

```
-(IBAction)btnHomeAction
{

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://test.xyz.com/refferel";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    vWTop.hidden=YES;
    vWBottom.hidden=YES;
    _webView.hidden=YES;


    CGRect rect = _webView.frame;
    rect.origin.y =  20;
    rect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height-20;

    _webView.frame=rect;

}
```

Comment: `_webView.hidden=YES;` Are you setting it no NO after web view finished loading?

Comment: You have check via UIWebView Delegate. `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;`
, `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;`, 
`- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;`

Comment: No ... There is nothing like this i used.
all the web pages are running fine.But on a click on the button i am not able to go on that exact url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is creating the problem,

```
_webView.hidden=YES;
```

Remove this line or make the webView visible again once the page is loaded

By removing the above line should work. Make sure the URL is also valid. Try opening the URL in your browser. And if the URL is fine then making sure that webView is not hidden will solve the problem.

**If you don't want t remove that line then to make it visible again after the webView finishes loading**

- You need to conform to UIWebViewDelegate in your class header file

> ```
>  @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
> ```

- You need to set the delegate

> _webView.delegate = self

- Make the webView visible when it finishes loading

> ```
> - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
>     _webView.hidden=NO;
> }
> ```

Comment: vote up requires minimum 15 reputation. i am new to stackoverflow .. so i cant.. sorry  :(

Comment: no probs ... glad to help. Reputation can come later. :)